# Channel attributes to provide barriers in MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

What channel attributes can be utilized to provide barriers at different points in WebSphere MQ Inbound channel processing as an alternative to just simply disabling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a security perspective, the approach of using multiple controls on a channel definition provides some redundancy.  For example, many years ago researchers found a bug (which IBM quickly fixed) in the channel protocol that allowed the channel to start despite an `MCAUSER` that should have prevented the connection.  If the MQ admin had relied entirely on the `MCAUSER` value, the channels would have been vulnerable until the fix was applied.

For that reason I generally advise to set multiple controls in the channels that you wish to be disabled.  The idea is that if one control fails, the channel fails to a safe state.  You could, for example, use `CHLAUTH` to disable a channel but if you then use the Broker's New Broker Configuration Wizard, the first thing it does (last time I checked) is to disable `CHLAUTH`.  Whoops.

Here are a few of the attributes that can be used to disable a channel.  Remember that if you apply these to a `SYSTEM.DEF.*` or `SYSTEM.AUTO.*` channel, you *must* override the attribute on creating a new legitimate channel so do not go overboard and use all of them.  Or, more precisely, use one control for every layer of tin foil present in your favorite hat.  ;-)

- Set `MCAUSER('*NOBODY')` because the asterisk is not a valid character in a user ID.
- Set the max message length to something shorter than the `MQMD` length.
- Set `SSLCIPH`, `SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)` and make sure `SSLPEER` has an impossible value.
- Use `CHLAUTH` rules but make sure that when you create the rules that allow access on legitimate channels that they are not so broad as to authorize access to channels you did not intend.
- Specify exits that do not exist.

Note that these address the issue of an attacker who does not already have access to the QMgr.  Any attacker with admin access will keep templates on hand from a `saveqmgr` from each MQ version.  This allows the attacker to submit `DEFINE` commands that contain all the required attributes and thus will not be reliant on the `SYSTEM.*` objects.  The legitimate administrator, however, must use the same approach or at least be cognizant of which attributes must be overridden to define a new channel.

In short, this approach provides perimeter controls and the trade off is in administrative overhead.  To be effective, use two or more unrelated controls (`CHLAUTH`, `MCAUSER` and invalid exit spec, for example), incorporate the setting into the training for administrators, and do not be tempted to use every possible control because the cost of doing so rises faster than the benefit.

Answer (score 1):

The most appropriate thing to use to provide barriers for inbound channels is the CHLAUTH rules introduced in V7.1. This allows you to block/allow inbound channels based on IP Address (or host name in V8), remote queue manager name or client side user ID, or Certificate Subject's DN (and/or Issuer's DN in V8).